# Edittext Not Accesable in onNewIntent Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I trying to access the edit text in the `onNewIntent()`but it is throwing me the null pointer exception.

**Exception :**

```
10-01 13:20:03.516: E/AndroidRuntime(18170): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-01 13:20:03.516: E/AndroidRuntime(18170): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-01 13:20:03.516: E/AndroidRuntime(18170):    at com.iween.exampleTest.FirstPage.onNewIntent(FirstPage.java:177)
10-01 13:20:03.516: E/AndroidRuntime(18170):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnNewIntent(Instrumentation.java:1155)
10-01 13:20:03.516: E/AndroidRuntime(18170):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverNewIntents(ActivityThread.java:2279)
10-01 13:20:03.516: E/AndroidRuntime(18170):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performNewIntents(ActivityThread.java:2292)
10-01 13:20:03.516: E/AndroidRuntime(18170):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleNewIntent(ActivityThread.java:2301)
10-01 13:20:03.516: E/AndroidRuntime(18170):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:149)
10-01 13:20:03.516: E/AndroidRuntime(18170):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1371)
10-01 13:20:03.516: E/AndroidRuntime(18170):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-01 13:20:03.516: E/AndroidRuntime(18170):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
10-01 13:20:03.516: E/AndroidRuntime(18170):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
10-01 13:20:03.516: E/AndroidRuntime(18170):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-01 13:20:03.516: E/AndroidRuntime(18170):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-01 13:20:03.516: E/AndroidRuntime(18170):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
10-01 13:20:03.516: E/AndroidRuntime(18170):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
10-01 13:20:03.516: E/AndroidRuntime(18170):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Code of onNewItent**

```
@Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        edit1.getText().clear();

    }
```

**LogoutCOde**

```
clickToLogout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this,
                        Firstpage.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

Comment: i will suggest you to perform null check for edit1 before getting text

Comment: your question is not clear. please provide more info

Answer (score 0):

please check [onNewIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29) it is used for using the previous instance of the `Activity` from backstack. if your `edit1` is not initialized it will give you `NPE`.

**EDIT**

What i understood is

your `FirstPage.java` is login page and `Home.java` is your Home after logging in and when you logout from home screen you come to `FirstPage.java` and then you want clear you `EditText` for credentials.

So if this is the case then you can use `noHistory` for `FirstPage.java` so that it wont stay in your `backstack` and so that you don't have to track `backstack` manually on normal backpress in `Home.java`. Then you can start your `FirstPage.java` on logout like

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this,FirstPage.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)); 
startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: so how could i get out from this issue

Comment: show your code what you are trying to do and why you are using this method

Comment: if i doing this if(edit1 !=null){
 edit1.getText().clear();
} it is not shwwing the acticity

Comment: i am using this for a logout functinality

Comment: whats in your activity? paste your code in question and please read the documentation for which i posted a link

Comment: Preserve your variables and objects state at class level variables before calling OnNewIntent. and the reset them in noNewIntent call.

Comment: i am not getting you @Macrosoft-Dev and i am doing any check in OnNewIntent it is showing a blank page to me .

Comment: @Macrosoft-Dev onNewIntent is activity method.its android who call it.

Comment: @Siddhesh onPause() is called before onNewIntent(), and then afterwards it calls onResume(). So done your work in onpause() and reset screen in OnResume().

Comment: any sample for that i am not geting you

Comment: @Rahul this site is for people like you and me. its not that your code will be stolen. there are more awesome code on this site people doesn't bother to post it here as it helps other. so no need of email id. paste it in your question.

Comment: on device back press it will show all the previous states of the activity

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38418/discussion-between-rahul-and-siddhesh)